# Make converter for columnSpan

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I would like to dynamic do the columnSpan on the userControl. I created the converter class, but it didn’t work. Would you show me how to do it correctly? Thanks.

The code on my UserControl:

```
<TextBlock  x:Name="txtSumary" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding summary}"           
   TextWrapping="Wrap"  Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextAccentStyle}" Grid.ColumnSpan="{Binding isSpan, Converter={StaticResource ColumSpanConverter}}"  />
```

It is reference on the  UserControl.Resources

```
<local:VisibilityConverter x:Key="ColumSpanConverter"/>
```

There is the Converter Class:

```
 public class ColumSpanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {          
        bool isSpan = (bool)value;
        return isSpan ? 2 : 0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converter is referencing the wrong converter:

```
<local:VisibilityConverter x:Key="ColumSpanConverter"/>
```

Should be:

```
<local:ColumSpanConverter x:Key="ColumSpanConverter" />
```

Comment: Thanks to point out my mistake. Also I found that I should return 1 instead of 0 on the Convert function.